# How can i post and return a value in a Webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

My Webservice method:

```
@Path("/getFaehigkeiten")
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")  
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public List<Faehigkeit> getFaehigkeiten(String art){
     List<Faehigkeit> ret =null;
      try {
          ret=Database.getInstance().getFaehigkeiten(art);

     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return ret;
    }
```

And so i call it:

```
public void getFaehigkeiten(String art){
        service.path("Faehigkeit").path("getFaehigkeit").post(art);

    }
```

But how can i return the List? I can not use @post and @get in the same web-service method?

Comment: Why would you need to use `@GET`? What is returned as a response to the post is the `List<Faehigkeit>` returned by the method. Using text/plain to return a list of objects seems like a strange idea, though.

Comment: because i can't write: List<Faehigkeit> help = service.path("Faehigkeit").path("getFaehigkeiten").post(art);

Comment: What is the client API you're using? Where is its javadoc?

Comment: And where is the javadoc of this post() method? I'm pretty sure it returns something.